# Windows 10 Hosts file not working Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, windows-10, homestead, hosts

I am trying to get windows to redirect homestead.localhost to the site i have setup in Laravel *Homestead*. But its not letting me access the page. i can access the site i setup by going to 192.168.10.10 but going to http://homestead.localhost in my browser brings up:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My windows host file, the only line in it, has

> 192.168.10.10 homestead.localhost

And here is my Homestead.yaml:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/Users/jarro/Documents/Sites
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites

sites:
    - map: homestead.localhost
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites/homestead

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

So the question is, why is my windows 10 host not working.

I have did the following:

**Cleared IP Config, Restarted computer, deleted and created a new vagrant, and reloaded the vagrant.**

What am i missing?

Comment: Any help is appreciated! I am really new to Laravel and editing windows hosts. I always used Ampps in the past and it edited everything for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after about a week of giving up, i decided to go back and try again. Found a post on Laracasts:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-windows-10-need-to-specify-port-8000

All you have to do to fix what i am having done is add :8000 on the url and the site loads. Its not working on port 80 for some reason. I am gonna go fix this now so i can rest in peace.

:D

Comment: Well sure, Homestead automatically maps port 80 to port 8000 for you. Don't fix it, it's the way it should be.

Answer (score 0):

> sites:
>       - map: homestead.localhost
>         to: /home/vagrant/Sites/homestead

You have to map your site to the "public" folder of your Laravel Project! Something like:

to: /home/vagrant/Sites/myLaravelProject/public

Homestead doesn't have any index.php which could be referenced.

Comment: Where is the public folder?

Comment: You are incorrect. i can access my website via http://192.168.10.10. the files are not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but in the Hosts file I find it much easier to just use:

127.0.0.1  myapp.local

It works everytime. I have always had minor problems with using 192.168.10.10